# The intervals $[-1,1)$ and $(-1,1)$ are not homeomorphic

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

[image]

Would someone please  help me out with that. I print Screen for everything I have done so far. The assumption is missing.

Comment: Instead of asking us to read your professor's mind, it'd be better to ask the professor. I would guess s/he wanted to see "Suppose that they are homeomorphic" at the beginning of proof.

Comment: Maybe she meant that you should clarify that $f$ is a homeomorphism between $[-1,1)$ and $(1,1)$? Otherwise it looks fine.

Comment: $f([-1,1)-\{-1\})=(-1,1)-\{f(-1)\}.$

Answer (score 0):

You have assumed there is a homeomorphism $$f:[-1,1)\to(-1,1).$$
 You then looked at the restriction of $f$ to $[-1,1) \setminus \{-1\} = (-1,1)$. You would then need to prove that this restriction is also a homeomorphism once you've also restricted the codomain to $(-1,1) \setminus \{f(-1)\}$.

As an aside, the same proof can be used to show that $\mathbb{R}$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$.